# Populating array of Id's with aggregation in mongoose

Tags: mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to populate array of id's in aggregation method using $lookup in mongoose. I am using mongoose  6.6.2.
Here is how I am storing data in mongoDB
[image]

and this is the query I am using

```
await mongoose.models.xyz.aggregate([
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: '$dietaries',
            localField: 'dietaries',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'dietaries'
          }
        }
      ]);
```

I am getting empty array as return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem is with this line  `from: '$dietaries'`

If your collection is named "dietaries", it should be `from: 'dietaries'`. You don't need the `$` there.